# C++ reading and writing data from a map that contains boost::any in a xml or json format

Tags: c++, json, xml, serialization, boost

This is how the map is declared: `std::map<const std::string,boost::any> data`

I want to make a function that writes all the data from the map to a file and another function that reads it and initializes the map with the data and the corresponding data type.

I've read some old posts from like 10 years ago that say that its no possible, has anything changed?

Comment: Which part do you think may be impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that the boost::any only references one of a few datatypes, then you can explicitly check for them, and handle each case explicitly. For example, if you were using the [Nlohmann Json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for json serialization, you could do the following:

```
nlohmann::json json_rep;
for(auto const& kv: data)
{
    auto const& key = kv.first;
    auto const& value = kv.second;
    auto const& type = value.type();
    if(type == typeof(std::string))
        json_rep[key] = boost::any_cast<std::string>(value);
    else if(type == typeof(int))
        json_rep[key] = boost::any_cast<int>(value);
    else if(type == typeof(double))
        json_rep[key] = boost::any_cast<double>(value);
    else if(type == typeof(MyCustomType))
        json_rep[key] = boost::any_cast<MyCustomType>(&value)->to_json();
    // etc...
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid data type in data");
}
```

Unfortunately, if there is no bound for the datatype of the `any`, then there is no general solution.